# XDocument.save() doesn't work

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using visual studio 2015 to make a application for windows desktop.
I try to open insert an element and save the document but when I use the fonction `.Save()`, it doesn't save the file

here is my code

```
String filePath = "person.xml";
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    XDocument collection = XDocument.Load(filePath);
    XElement person = new XElement("user",
                            new XElement("id", this.getId()),
                            new XElement("name", this.getName()),
                            new XElement("info", this.getInfo()));
    collection.Element("root").Add(person);
    using (var file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (var stream = file.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            collection.Save(stream);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    XDeclaration declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes");
    XDocument collection = new XDocument(declaration);
    XElement person = new XElement("root",
                        new XElement("user",
                            new XElement("id", this.getId()),
                            new XElement("name", this.getName()),
                            new XElement("info", this.getInfo())));
    collection.Add(person);
    using (var file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (var stream = file.CreateFile(filePath))
        {
            collection.Save(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

but when I try to load the file, it go to the error, the file doesn't exist

EDIT : 
code to load the xml :

```
XDocument collection = XDocument.Load("person.xml");
        foreach(XElement a in collection.Descendants("user")) {
            Person temp = new Person((int)a.Element("id"), (string)a.Element("info"), (string)a.Element("name"));
            lPerson.Add(temp);
            lPerson.nbPerson++;

        }
```

Comment: Any exceptions or other messages? Or does it just run through normally but nothing happens?

Comment: If you go to %localappdata%\IsolatedStorage\, can you find your file there?

Comment: @CodingGorilla it  just run through normaly

Comment: @cFronzenDeath no ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a filestream for that.

Just do a collection.Save(filename);

edit:
Did you intend to try to write the person.xml file to collections.xml?  You're trying to open in as collection.xml but I don't see where you saved it that way.

If you are just writing back the file, then use this:

```
collection.Element("root").Add(person);
collection.Save(filepath)'
```

edit#2:
if you're trying to write to isolated storage, you're going to need to do it differently.  Here's the document I found on how to do it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189085%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: Please delete this, as it's not a real answer. You can't write to the IsolatedStorage like this.

Comment: It works on my machine. In fact, his top code he's already got the filename defined from the load, so he doesn't even need anything more than collections.save() on that one.

Comment: i've try that but when I do so I have : Impossible to convert string into System.IO.Stream

Comment: The line after you do the collection.Add(person), just do collection.Save(filepath);  You don't need to do a using file or open a filestream.

Comment: my ide doesn't want :/

Comment: Was it necessary to downvote my answer, cFrozenDeath?  I was honestly trying to help, and I believe my original answer (and the update) provided some valid help, especially as no one else bothered to try to help him at all for hours.  Instead, now I'm blocked from even trying to answer anyone else.  Thanks. I guess you see other people trying to help as mere competition. Btw, deleting my answer would have done the same thing as downvoting it.

Comment: Yes, it's necessary as most of the information this answer provides is incorrect for this question. If you change it to provide only meaningful information, it will be less helpful than mine or a copy, that's why you should delete it.

Comment: It's not "necessary".  Deleting it would have the identical effect as your downvote.  Deleting it doesn't help me.  And no, most of the answer is not incorrect.  He was trying to write the same file back but read a different file.  He also didn't need to open a filestream.  Only part of his problem was the isolated storage, not ALL.  You could have simply left my answer as a 0 but instead you chose to actively screw me over because my reputation is still low here.

Comment: It may not have helped the OP, but it helped me. I was getting an unable to write to file while in use by another process, and it was because I was grabbing the file twice. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Laki glad it was able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your first if sentence will always be false unless you explicitly create a file "person.xml" where your application is stored. What you want is something like what I'm pasting below.

```
string fileName = "person.xml";

using (IsolatedStorageFile isoManager = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (isoManager.FileExists(fileName))
    {
        XDocument collection = XDocument.Load(fileName);
        XElement person = new XElement("user",
            new XElement("id", "someid"),
            new XElement("name", "someName"),
            new XElement("info", "someInfo"));
        collection.Element("root").Add(person);
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileWriter = isoManager.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
           using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileWriter))
           {
               collection.WriteTo(writer);
           }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        XDeclaration declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes");
        XDocument collection = new XDocument(declaration);
        XElement person = new XElement("root",
           new XElement("user",
           new XElement("id", "someid"),
           new XElement("name", "someName"),
           new XElement("info", "someInfo")));
        collection.Add(person);
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileWriter = isoManager.CreateFile(fileName))
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileWriter))
            {
                collection.WriteTo(writer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: your read method will never work unless you create the file "collections.xml" where your application is stored, use something like this:

```
string fileName = "collections.xml";

using (IsolatedStorageFile isoManager = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (isoManager.FileExists(fileName))
    {
        XDocument document;
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream reader = isoManager.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            document = XDocument.Load(reader);
        }
        foreach (XElement a in document.Descendants("user"))
        {
             Person temp = new Person((int)a.Element("id"), (string)a.Element("info"), (string)a.Element("name"));
             lPerson.Add(temp);
             lPerson.nbPerson++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution work and don't work in the same time ... i don't know how but the file is not created , and i can load it with the information. But if I reload the app, the file no longer exist :/

Comment: @Alann just so we are clear, aren't you getting an exception trying to access the IsolatedStorage?

Comment: sorry , i changed isoManager.FileExist by File.Exist because isoManager return true even if the file doesn't exist, if I let the isoManager i have an exception because he try to open a file which doesn't exist

Comment: yes i'm sure
I have try so many things to save my xml file but nothing work :/
I just want to store some information in a file to use them later and I'm stuck on this problem ...

Comment: This works perfectly on my computer. The file is generated at: %localappdata%\IsolatedStorage\k4d0zh3d.30g\r0eeufot.pg2\StrongName.hnc3uqrhm23qfelf35gkmqa1mbazb0ah\AppFiles\person.xml. FYI, I'm under Windows10, but I think this is the same in Windows 8 and 7

Comment: Beware, however, that I'm saving "persons.xml" and then reading "persons.xml", not "collections.xml" which you never save

Comment: my bad ... it's for work and i have to change the name of file or else... this is the same name in my code

Comment: @Alann you can just save it as "collection.xml" or "persons.xml", but you need to save it and read it using the same name. What I posted works perfectly in my VS

Comment: they have the same name but what you posted doesn't work on my VS :/

Comment: when i use your code, isoManager.FileExist(fileName) return true when the file is not created ...so I have a error : Could not find file 'C:\Users\Alann\Desktop\project\CollectionProject\CollectionProject\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\person.xml'.

Comment: @Alann You are definitively **NOT** using the code I provided. Look at your file path, that's **NOT** the IsolatedStorage location for your application. You have something wrong. isoManager.FileExists(fileName) works perfectly for me: if I delete the file, it returns false. Also, note that the IsolatedStorage should be something like: C:\Users\Alann\appdata\local\isolatedstorage\ **randomName** \ **randomNameAgain** \application files\person.xml

Comment: @cFronzenDeath I'm using the code you provided but it's not my fault if on my computer I have this error ...

Comment: @cFronzenDeath : your code work well if I want to load the document, but the only problem with your code is isoManager.FileExist which return true when it should return false ...

Comment: @Alann you are still not understanding. The file **DOES** exist, if you are not able to find it, it doesn't mean it doesn't exist. The function can never return true if the file doesn't exist. And the error indicates that you are using other code somewhere, as I already explained